# Word automation with c# updating field expression

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation

I'm using automation to update protected "fill-in" form fields in a word document created by someone else. The document contains a couple readonly "calculation" fields as well with =SUM() formulas in the expression-property of that field.

I can find the fields and add text/values to them but one of the problems I have is that readonly fields with expressions are not calculated. If I open up the word document afterwords and tab from one field to another the expression is calculated properly, but I'd like to have these fields calculated from my code as you understand :)

Any ideas how to do it? I'm guessing there's a metod or something that I can call on the field or range object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a method on the field called Update() which seems to do what I'm looking for!